# VS2013 can't replace content with $1, why?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, replace, zero-width-space

I am using VS2013, and i want replace some text. Because the file has many alike word， so i have to use regex look ahead, look behind so search and replace.

text.txt:

```
abc adc
```

regex:

```
(?<=a)([a-z])(?=c)
```

and replace with

```
xxx$1xxx
```

But failed to replace all, Anyone konw this why?

Comment: may be vs2013 replace dosen't support regex look-ahead ...